# how to query in the substrate node?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end

I want to get collection data using collectionId 1
the collection was created on the on the node already with the id 1. How can I do this is substrate? Any CLI tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) (Rust)
- [polkadotJs API](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api) (JavaScript)

If you do **not** want to query programmatically, you can use:

- https://polkadot.js.org/apps